# How can I switch to/from dark mode depending on "darkness" instead of sunset?

Tags: macos, big-sur, dark-mode

On BigSur the Sunset-Detector works but it doesn't make sense, because in the real world darkness arrives a bit earlier than sunset. It hurts my eyes, because I stay focused on my work and don't notice that it's dark already.

How can I have macOS toggle dark mode earlier/later than sunset/sunrise for whatever location I'm currently in?

Comment: You could change your time zone.

Comment: @JasonConrad what if my timezone is dynamic. I don't want to play with the settings every week. Also messing with timezone means wrong _time/calendar/weather/reminder/alarm_ information. So I think this solution will definitely not work.

Comment: Well, not to mention all of the other collateral damage that might cause.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but dude just go dark all the way. Trust me.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you (and third party developers) don’t get to automate this since it’s a private API. This article explains the situation in great detail and offers three tools to get you close to customizing it.

- https://setapp.com/how-to/use-night-shift-for-mac

> First, turn the night shift off under “Schedule” in the night shift menu. This disables it schedule from activating, but doesn’t disable the feature.

I wonder if your setup is the ambient light sensor changing and not the schedule, though.

> It will activate when it notices your environment is darker than normal, and disable itself when you’re back to daylight or bright environments.

> Keep in mind this option will trigger automatically, which can be frustrating if you’re in a spot where the light fluctuates.

Short of using an automation tool to define your own preferred schedule or just [automate toggling this manually](https://www.40tech.com/2018/09/30/use-launchbar-to-toggle-dark-mode-in-mojave/), you can use Apple’s implementation or just take breaks and manage your lighting external to the display.

Some excellent automation tools include

- https://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html
- https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/

Comment: Keyboard Maestro allows toggling of Dark Mode, for instance. And https://sunrise-sunset.org/api offers a API to get sunrise/sunset times depending on location.

Comment: @nohillside you are amazing. The script is pretty easy to toggle with automation, but API is icing on top!

Comment: @nohillside thanks for the API, I'll write a program myself :D